# C++ / Share variable or send data from unmanaged to managed in the same DLL

Tags: c++, dll, unmanaged, managed

I Have a mixed mode DLL containing a unmanaged part (DllMain) and a managed C++ part.

I calculate some folders in DllMain and I want to share/send data to the managed part when it is called.

I load DLL using LoadLibrary from another C++ program.

How can I share data or send data from DllMain to the managed part ?

I have to share/send some char*.

Thanks

Comment: That is illegal, what you can do in DllMain() is severely restricted due to the loader lock.  Calling managed code is most certainly out, the CLR cannot be loaded.  Using __declspec(dllexport) is a simple way to provide an entrypoint that a native C++ program can call.  But beware the cost, managed code likes throwing exceptions and you're blind as a bat when that happens.  Hosting the CLR or using a [ComVisible] class are the better ways.

Answer (score 0):

You need to export a native function from the managed DLL, which native DLL can call upon. 
Or, you can have an interface (C++ interface), powered by a `CreateThisObject` or similar, which will instantiate the derived-class (of interface). This interface, as well as the creation-function will be given by managed DLL, and native DLL will simply use it as normal C++ class.

Kind-of pseudo-code is presented below

```
// Export function only
EXPORT
int DoSomethingInManagedDLL(args);

// Export hidden class, through an interface
class IDLLHelper
{
   virtual void DoSomething() = 0;
};

EXPORT IDLLHelper* CreateDLLHelper();

// Some class, known only to managed DLL
// This class, as well as above' interface is native

class DLLHelperImpl : public IDLLHelper
{
   void DoSomething()
   {
    // actual code
   }
};
```

Comment: Hello, i don't understand how to implement that, I have a public ref class, which is my managed code, this class should get the values from DLLMain function.

Comment: `DllMain` is entry point, not a function in itself. The unmanaged DLL will not understand managed stuff, and therefore you need to export something **native** from managed DLL, so that unmanaged DLL can call it.

Comment: Ok but when DllMain is executed, the clr is not loaded. The clr is only loaded when I try to execute a class compiled with the clr flag.

Comment: But why do need something when `DllMain` is executing? Why not when DLL is fully loaded?

Comment: I want to get current Dll filename and filepath.

Comment: Then your question is wrong. It doesn't ask what it should. 
Refer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I already used this function in DllMain. I get what I wanted but I can't use it in my managed part.